# Enabling mutual auth with tomcat buildpack on bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, tomcat8, buildpack

I have created a J2ee web application and i am pushing it on bluemix with tomcat java_buildpack. Now i would like to enable the mutual auth on the server and would like to modify the tomcat's server.xml to enable mutual and assign a keystore.I am not able to find a way how to do that.

Can you please help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried modifying the provided `server.xml` and deploying it to an `external_configuration` as mentioned in its documentation? https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/blob/master/docs/container-tomcat.md

Comment: I am not sure how to pass only the server.xml file here   JBP_CONFIG_TOMCAT: "{ tomcat: { external_configuration_enabled: true }, external_configuration: { repository_root: \"http://repository...\" } }"    If i just write server.xml and copy the file in the current folder...it does not work

Comment: I am getting this error while pushing after adding external configuration  [ConfigurationUtils]             WARN  User config value for '{"external_configuration_enabled"=>true}' is not valid, existing property not present
[ConfigurationUtils]             WARN  User config value for 'server.xml' is not valid, existing property not present